# Is there a base type for method pointers?

Tags: delphi

In the following code I have two method pointer types defined. I need another procedure that accepts a parameter of any of these types and uses it based on other values. But I cannot find a base type for these two types to be able to pass both into the procedure:

```
type
  TIntProc: procedure (I: Integer) of object;
  TStrProc: procedure (S: string) of object;

....

  procedure TForm1.CallbackTest(A: Integer; Callback: procedure of object {What type should I use here?});
  var
    IntProc: TIntProc;
    StrProc: TStrProc;   
  begin
    if A = 1 then begin
      IntProc:= TIntProc(Callback);
      IntProc(100);
    end else begin
      StrProc:= TStrProc(Callback);
      StrProc('Hello');
    end;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.MyIntProc(I: Integer);
  begin
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(I));
  end;

  procedure TForm1.MyStrProc(S: string);
  begin
    ShowMessage(S);
  end;
```

I should be able to write:

```
CallbackTest(1, MyIntProc);
```

and also:

```
CallbackTest(2, MyStrProc);
```

But certainly I get errors on both because `procedure of object` used as the type of second parameter is not a base type for `procedure (I: Integer) of object` and `procedure (S: string) of object`. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no inheritance for procedural types. You cannot have a type safe way to pass either type via a single argument. You would need to cast. For example you could [typecast](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Typecasts) between the procedural type variables and [`TMethod`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TMethod).

```
// Health warning, this code is for illustration, I do not endorse its use

procedure Foo(A: Integer; Callback: TMethod);
begin
  if A = 1 then
    TIntProc(Callback)(100)
  else
    TStrProc(Callback)('Hello');
end;

....

Foo(1, TMethod(IntProc));
Foo(2, TMethod(StrProc));
```

But I would not recommend that approach if a better one is available. Not least because you have to use unchecked casts and so do not even benefit from runtime checking that is available for classes with the `as` operator.

Personally I'd tackle this a different way:

```
public
  procedure Foo(Callback: TIntProc); overload;
  procedure Foo(Callback: TStrProc); overload;
```

If you need a single routine to handle both callback methods, make an extra private overload:

```
private
  procedure Foo(IntCallback: TIntProc; StrCallback: TStrProc); overload;
```

Implement like this:

```
procedure TMyClass.Foo(IntCallback: TIntProc; StrCallback: TStrProc); 
begin
  if Assigned(IntCallback) then
    ....
  if Assigned(StrCallback) then
    ....
end;
```

And then implement the public overloads like this:

```
procedure TMyClass.Foo(Callback: TIntProc);
begin
  Foo(Callback, nil);
end;

procedure TMyClass.Foo(Callback: TStrProc);
begin
  Foo(nil, Callback);
end;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on typecasting to TMethod? I have to use method pointers and the overloading solution doesn't fit my requirements.

Comment: The overloading approach fits the question. Perhaps your real problem is different from the question. You say, "I have to use method pointers". Fine. The code in my answer uses method pointers.  Why do you feel compelled to abandon type safety? Do you understand the consequences of that?

Comment: As for typecasting, I assumed you knew what a typecast was. I linked to the docs for typecasting. Do you know what a typecast is? I'm just trying to work out what level to pitch this.

Comment: Sure I do. But was looking for a sample of typecasting to TMethod and back. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can just do that. Typecast if you wish. I mean I would not, but it's obviously your choice.

Comment: I chose to typecast because the actual procedure should keep references of these callbacks and TMethod did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

With a little generic help this is possible:

```
program Project14;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,TypInfo;

Type
  TMyProcedures = record
    procedure MyIntProc(I: Integer);
    procedure MyStrProc(S: String);
  end;

  TMyRec = record
    public
      class procedure CallbackTest<T>( Callback: TProc<T>); static;
  end;

class procedure TMyRec.CallbackTest<T>( Callback: TProc<T>);
begin
  case GetTypeKind(T) of
  tkInteger:
    begin
      if GetTypeData(TypeInfo(T))^.OrdType = otSLong then
        TProc<Integer>(Callback)(100);
    end;
  tkUString:
    TProc<String>(Callback)('Hello');
  end;
  else raise Exception.Create('Callback type can only be string or integer');
end;

procedure TMyProcedures.MyIntProc(I: Integer);
begin
  WriteLn(IntToStr(I));
end;

procedure TMyProcedures.MyStrProc(S: string);
begin
  WriteLn(S);
end;

var
  myProcedures: TMyProcedures;

begin
  TMyRec.CallbackTest<Integer>(myProcedures.MyIntProc);
  TMyRec.CallbackTest<String>(myProcedures.MyStrProc);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

The kind of method is resolved by a `TypeInfo` call, and a typecast fixes the callback method.

For versions prior to Delphi XE7 you can use the following code for `CallBackTest`

```
class procedure TMyRec.CallbackTest<T>( Callback: TProc<T>);
begin
  if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(Integer) then begin
      if GetTypeData(TypeInfo(T))^.OrdType = otSLong then
        TProc<Integer>(Callback)(100);
  end
  else if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(String) then begin
    TProc<String>(Callback)('Hello');
  end
  else raise Exception.Create('Callback type can only be string or integer');
end;
```

---

<sub>Updated with a typesafe way to separate the actual ordinal type to an integer and code that will work for Delphi 2009..XE6.</sub>

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I have to use method pointers (i.e. `procedure of object`).

Comment: this works for `procedure of object` and for simple procedures. just give it a try.

Comment: GetTypeKind lets the compiler make the choice rather than having runtime switches

Comment: @Delphi.Boy, TProc<T> is a reference to a procedure. This means that you can pass both a method (procedure of object) and a normal procedure.

Comment: FWIW, the implementation of `TMyRec.CallbackTest<T>` is about as non-generic as can be imagined. I'd certainly expect to see some sort of a warning about such code being, er, far from ideal.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, you mean the part with tkInteger not resolving the actual ordinal type?

Comment: No, I mean that generics are strong when you write a single block of code that is expanded multiple times for different types. If you have to expand for each type manually then what is the point of using generics. Compared to overloading, say, you write the same amount of code, but lose compile time type checking. The compiler is happy your method to be called with any type being passed, even though at runtime there is only support for two specific types.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, but in your first example, if the the first parameter does not match the passed method, it is not resolved at compile time either. I agree that the overloaded example is better, As for using RTTI to resolve generic information, I wish there were better ways to constrain the type in the declaration to sort out mistakes during compilation.

Comment: @LURD Indeed. The use of casting in the first example in my code is a bad solution in my view, and I think I made my opinion clear! Generic constraints are a little weak. Templates would not have this problem.