# Procedure of object how to change the _self?

Tags: delphi, self

I have

```
Type
  TProcOfObject = Procedure of Object;

var 
  MyProc: TProcOfObject;
```

now if I do

```
MyProc := MyObject.MyProc
```

then when I will call MyProc self will be equal to MyObject (I do not yet fully understand where self is stored in MyProc). Is their a way to call myProc with another value than MyObject for Self ?

Comment: Related : [Passing a method's code as an argument in a typesafe way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9721396/327083)

Comment: Related : [How to store different method pointers in one container in delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47294601/327083)

Comment: Related : [Is there a base type for method pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32110153/327083)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I do not yet fully understand where self is stored in MyProc

A method pointer is represented by the [`TMethod`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TMethod) record, which contains 2 pointers as members - `Data` points to the `Self` object, and `Code` points to the beginning of the method's code.

When a method pointer is invoked as a function at compile-time, the compiler outputs codegen which executes the `Code` passing in the `Data` as the `Self` parameter.

> Is their a way to call myProc with another value than MyObject for Self ?

You can type-cast the method pointer to `TMethod` to access its inner pointers, eg:

```
var 
  MyProc: TProcOfObject;

...

TMethod(MyProc).Data := ...; // whatever value you want Self to be
TMethod(MyProc).Code := ...; // whatever function you want to call

...

MyProc();
```